# Как обходить защиту от бота CLoudFlare или Qrator

Tags: python, selenium

День добрый!
При использование Selenium, очень часто попадаются сайты, которые определяют заход как бот.
Я использую смену юзер-агента, персональные прокси, изменения черех hex редактор cdc_ , но все равно сервер определяет меня как робота.

Кто как обходит такие проверки? Пример сайтов citilink.ru , auchan.ru

Comment: Как-то гуглил как сайты определяют селениум и на английском стеке было написано, что селениум заполняет какие-то поля, доступные из javascript. И, по моему, каким-то флагом можно убирать их либо сделать это через javascript

Comment: @gil9red я тоже гуглил, вроде все перепробовал, пока тщетно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947 обратите внимание, например, на `Changing the property value of navigator for webdriver to undefined as follows`

Comment: @gil9red пробовал, не работает, я как раз таки эту тему и читал. У вас запустилось?

Comment: Не, у моих парсерах на селениуме такой проблемы не было. Так что, я больше по теории обхода защиты :)